# Default Devise users integration in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I want in my application AdminUsers and normal Users. What Is the best way to have this?

What I tried is this. I started with a brand new rails app

```
rails new testadmin
```

added ActiveAdmin to the Gemfile

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
```

And generate the admin interface

```
rails generate active_admin:install
```

then following the instructions provided by the shell.

I have now AdminUsers in ActiveAdmin. I then generated a User model for Devise:

```
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

and added it to the Admin interface

```
rails generate active_admin:resource User
```

This seems to work as I now have a fancy User page with filters and the ability to add a new User, but whenever I try to add it (setting the email and a password), I get the following exception:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in Admin::UsersController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: encrypted_password, reset_password_token, reset_password_sent_at(1i), reset_password_sent_at(2i), reset_password_sent_at(3i), reset_password_sent_at(4i), reset_password_sent_at(5i), remember_created_at(1i), remember_created_at(2i), remember_created_at(3i), remember_created_at(4i), remember_created_at(5i), current_sign_in_at(1i), current_sign_in_at(2i), current_sign_in_at(3i), current_sign_in_at(4i), current_sign_in_at(5i), last_sign_in_at(1i), last_sign_in_at(2i), last_sign_in_at(3i), last_sign_in_at(4i), last_sign_in_at(5i), current_sign_in_ip, last_sign_in_ip
```

How to get what I'm after? Thanks

PS: I really hope they'll add ActiveAdmin and Devise as standard, out of the box components for Rails like Django has its admin interface and user model :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter the `attr-accessible` from the `User` model. Enter this into `app/admin/user.rb`

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :email
    f.input :password
    f.input :password_confirmation
  end
  f.buttons
end
```

Hope this helps